# I have created a private class "PathakP" but I am getting PathakP cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing

I tried to create a dialog box with Jbutton but when I am adding actionListener to it and passing the class to button which i have created to implements ActionListener I am getting "PathakP(Class Name) cannot be resolved to a type"

the code I have used is

```
   import java.awt.*;

   import javax.swing.*;

   import java.awt.event.*;

   public class GUI1 extends JFrame {

   private JTextField J;
   private Font pf,bf,itf,bif;
   private JRadioButton pb,bb,ib,bib;
   private ButtonGroup B;
   private JButton ab;

    public  GUI1(){
    super("To check the Font styles" );
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     J=new JTextField("This is the Text who's Font will be Changed pahtak is           with me ",40);
    add(J);
    pb=new JRadioButton("Plain Button",true);
    bb=new JRadioButton("Bold Button",false);
    bib=new JRadioButton("Bold & Italic Button",false);
    ib=new JRadioButton("Italic Button",false);
    ab=new JButton("PathakButton");
    add(ab);

    add(pb);
    add(bb);
    add(bib);
    add(ib);

    B=new ButtonGroup();
    B.add(pb);
    B.add(bb);
    B.add(bib);
    B.add(ib);

    pf=new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,15);
    bf=new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,15);
    itf=new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC,15);
    bif=new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,16);
    J.setFont(pf);      


    pb.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(pf));
    bb.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(bf));
    bib.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(bif));
    ib.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(itf));

    ab.addActionListener(new PathakP());
}
    private class HandlerClass implements  ItemListener{
  private Font font;
  public HandlerClass(Font f){
    font=f;
}

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    J.setFont(font);
}

     private class PathakP implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is just JOptionPane example");
    }

}


}

}
```

---

Main Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Apples {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI1 G=new GUI1();
    G.setVisible(true);
    G.setSize(500,250);
    G.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

---

I don't believe there is any error in the main class
I can troubleshoot this error by just creating another class outside but I want to know why it is not taking the class I have created and show unused in it

Comment: why is it `private`?

Comment: it does not matter even if i make it public  it display same error !!

so i can not access it outside this main class

Comment: you are defining it as a inner class

Comment: If you fix the indentations so we can see the structure iof your code, it may be possible to see the problem. Until then, good luck. I will definitely not be looking at the code as it is right now.

Comment: @sidgate yes i think so

Comment: @Andreas i am sorry for that ,will do it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PathakP` is written inside of `HandlerClass`. You have two solutions from there (after having corrected your bracket problem)

- Either write it inside of `GUI` instead and since you're calling it from the constructor, it will be binded to this instance of `GUI`
- Or, if you want to keep it within `HandlerClass`, you need to bind it to an instance of `HandlerClass` : `ab.addActionListener(new HandlerClass().new PathakP())`